# Android Virtual Device works only once

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-testing

When I Launched the My android Application using Android Virtual Device, It works fine for first time(After running AVD)

When I tried to retest my application, My AVD shows me error (Timeout Error).
I need to close avd and need to reopen to test my application, If I reopen it then it works fine for one time.

What are the solutions ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to restart the adb following below commands:

"ABSOLUTE_PATH_OF_ANDROID_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
"ABSOLUTE_PATH_OF_ANDROID_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" start-server

I am also facing same problem and restarting adb fixed my problem. I have created a ".bat" batch file with above described commands, I run it every time when I am facing this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, I will try out this now onwards.